# mat-tree from Angular material is not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, angular-material

'mat-tree' and a few more such tags from angular material are not working on Firefox.

In case of 'mat-tree', values are visible in the first node, but I am not able to expand first node. There is no error on console.

This is working fine on chrome and edge.